# How to log within a stored procedure that is encapsulated within a transaction

Tags: mysql-5.5, stored-procedures, transaction

I have a stored procedure, let us call it *sp_A* which calls other stored procedures, let us call them *sp_B* and *sp_C*. For the sake of consistency an *XA TRANSATCION* is started within *sp_A*. What I actually want to do is to log if the execution of *sp_B* or *sp_C* fails and if so, which were the arguments passed to the failing stored procedure.
But as *sp_B* and *sp_C* do some inserts in some tables, I need to do a *XA ROLLBACK* if *sp_B* or *sp_C* fails.

So my question is: **How can I log into a table while I am within a transaction
(or how to execute an insert statement outside of the transaction scope)?**

To give you a little example of what I want to do (I've simplyfied the code and renamed most of the parameters/variables used to focus on the problem, I would never dream of using parameter names like *a*, *b* or *c* ;-) ):

The stored procedure *sp_A* looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_A`
(
  IN a INT,
  IN b VARCHAR(64),
  OUT c INT
)
sp_label:BEGIN
  DECLARE l_errorMessage TEXT;
  DECLARE l_spSuccess INT;
  DECLARE l_errorOccured INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN
    SET l_errorOccured = 1;
  END;

  XA START 'sp_A';

  CALL sp_B(a, b, l_spSuccess);

  IF l_errorOccured OR (l_spSuccessResult < 0) THEN
    XA END 'sp_A';
    XA ROLLBACK 'sp_A';
    SET c = -1;
    SET l_errorMessage = CONCAT('CALL sp_B(', a, ', ', b, ', l_spSuccess);');
    CALL sp_Log(l_errorMessage);
    LEAVE sp_label;
  END IF;

  CALL sp_C(a, b, l_spSuccess);

  IF l_errorOccured OR (l_spSuccessResult < 0) THEN
    XA END 'sp_A';
    XA ROLLBACK 'sp_A';
    SET c = -2;
    SET l_errorMessage = CONCAT('CALL sp_C(', a, ', ', b, ', l_spSuccess);');
    CALL sp_Log(l_errorMessage);
    LEAVE sp_label;
  END IF;

  XA END 'sp_A';
  XA COMMIT 'sp_A';
  SET c = 1;
END;
```

The stored procedure *sp_B* looks like this (*sp_C* looks similar):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_B`
(
  IN a INT,
  IN b VARCHAR(64),
  OUT c INT
)
sp_label:BEGIN
  DECLARE l_errorMessage TEXT;
  DECLARE l_spSuccess INT;
  DECLARE l_errorOccured INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN
    SET l_errorOccured = 1;
  END;

  INSERT INTO `someTable` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (a, b);

  IF l_errorOccured THEN
    SET c = -1;
    SET l_errorMessage = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `someTable` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (', a, ', ', b, ');');
    CALL sp_Log(l_errorMessage);
    LEAVE sp_label;
  END IF;

  SET c = 1;
END;
```

*sp_Log* just inserts data into a table which I want to use as my *logging table*.

So actually the logging within *sp_A* works just fine (because the call to *sp_Log* is outside a transaction) but the logging within *sp_B* or *sp_C* won't work because by rolling back the transaction started in *sp_A*, the inserts done by the call of *sp_Log* within *sp_B* or *sp_C* are reverted of course.

(I have simplified the example, in *sp_B* and *sp_C*. There is more going on than just one simple insert statement and just to have more fun, there are transactions started and commited/rolled back within *sp_B* and *sp_C* as well.)

I would appreciate any hints you could give me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem's that one viable way of solving this issue is using a table engine that does not support transactions. In this case changing the table engine of the log tables from `InnoDB` to `MyISAM` solved the problem.